# RSA keys keys static generation

Tags: java, android, security, cryptography, jax-rs

I'm guiding myself with this answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4319496/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-in-java/), which explains how to use both AES and RSA.

I managed to successfully implement the AES part with an util class in which I use a passphrase to generate keys. This passphrase will not change, the purpose of this is to encrypt a password before encoding it and saving it to a database. Then whenever I need to decrypt this password I can do it with the same passphrase, which should generate the same key. I've got this working.

Now my question begins with RSA. I have to send via JSON through a Java JAX-RS web service the info to register an user. HTTPS/SSL is out of the question for... "tech" reasons. So instead I'm trying to at the very least, send the password encrypted with a public key.  and decrypt it with the private key on the server.

I then encrypt it with AES and store it in the database.

How would my client (android) know the public key before any of this even happens if I have to generate different keys every time?

Comment: As it uses ECB mode and SHA-1 for key derivation (later amended for PBKDF2) it shows you how not to use AES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to generate new RSA keys every time. You can simply encrypt with the public key each time. If the data is too large then you should try and use hybrid encryption (i.e. generate a random AES key each time, encrypt the message with it and then encrypt the AES key with the public key of the RSA key pair).

You can simply distribute the public key within your Android app.

It's probably best not to use symmetric encryption at the server, if you want to store passwords for authentication, generate a salt on the server and perform PBKDF2 on the password. Then store the salt and the result of PBKDF2. Then whenever an authentication attempt is made, retrieve the salt, perform the PBKDF2 function again and compare the result with the value in the database.

Comment: So what you are saying is, that I could generate RSA keys and store them somewhere, like a file (as text? like base64?), use my private key to decrypt whatever I get encrypted from my clients and safely distribute my public key (as text? as before something like base64?) so people can use it to encrypt in their client apps?

Comment: Basically yes. Of course if you are dealing with other apps, you must make sure that the other apps are safe as well. Furthermore the other apps must be able to trust your public key. One way to do that is to distribute the public key using a TLS protected website. Or sign it using your PGP private key, if you have one. Note that you could do worse than to use PGP containers for distribution as well.