# How can I decrypt text from one application in another application with asymmetric encryption?

Tags: java, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to understand how I can decrypt a String in one application that I have encrypted in a separate application.  I can do this when I am in a single application execution, and I use the PrivateKey from the same KeyPair that generated the PublicKey.  However, I want to encrypt the value in one application, and decrypt the value in another application.  Basically I have a web service sending value I do not want to be tampered with to an application, and I was planning to use asymmetric encryption to handle it.  Feel free to let me know if I am going about solving that the wrong way.

I have tried various encryption techniques, starting with Symmetric.  The issue I ran into with that is that the value is encrypted to the same text each time - not very useful if my goal is to keep someone from tampering with a value - once they know the encrypted version of some text, they will be able to use that in any request.  I have been trying to follow the standards here - https://www.veracode.com/blog/research/encryption-and-decryption-java-cryptography
I can get all my examples working in a single transaction doing the encrypt/decrypt - it is just when I try to encrypt in one request, and decrypt in a second request that I fail.

Here is my current working example:

```
package com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

/**
 * Security class for encrypting and decrypting Strings (that also works in WC ver 7 and above)
 *
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class SecurityTools {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityTools.class);

  private Cipher cipher;
  private IvParameterSpec initVector;
  private SecretKey secretKey;
  PrivateKey privateKeyParam;
  PublicKey publicKeyParam;
  private static SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();

  private static final String TRANSFORMATION = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding";
  private static final String ALGORITHM_SHORT = "RSA";
  private static final String RNG_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
  private static final String ALGORITHM = "PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256";
  private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";

  // exceptions
  private static final String _ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE = "illegal block size exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_BAD_PADDING = "bad padding exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALIDKEY = "invalidkey exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_PADDING = "padding exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM = "no such algorithm exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL = "passphrase is null.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM = "invalid algorithm exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING = "encoding not supported.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC = "invalid key spec exception.";

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public SecurityTools() throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering Constructor");
    }
    try {
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM_SHORT);
      generateIV();
      generateKeys();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting Constructor");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Encrypts a given plain text String, and returns the encrypted String
   *
   * @param plainText
   * @return
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public String encrypt(String plainText, PublicKey publicKey) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering encrypt");
    }

    String encryptedKey = null;
    try {
      byte[] byteToEncrypt = plainText.getBytes(UTF8);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
      byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(byteToEncrypt);
      encryptedKey = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedBytes);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
    } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
      logger.error(_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING, uee);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING, uee);
    } /*-catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      }*/

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting encrypt");
    }

    return encryptedKey;
  }

  /**
   * Decrypts a given encrypted String, and returns the plain text String
   *
   * @param cipherTextStr
   * @return
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public String decrypt(String cipherTextStr, PrivateKey privateKey) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering decrypt");
    }

    String cleartext = null;
    try {
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
      byte[] plainByte = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(cipherTextStr));
      cleartext = new String(plainByte);
    } /*-catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      } */catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
    } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting decrypt");
    }

    return cleartext;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the IV using Secure Random Number Generator and an empty 16byte array
   *
   * @return
   */
  private void generateIV() {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering generateIV");
    }

    byte[] newSeed = secureRandom.generateSeed(16);
    secureRandom.setSeed(newSeed);
    byte[] byteIV = new byte[16];
    secureRandom.nextBytes(byteIV);
    initVector = new IvParameterSpec(byteIV);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting generateIV");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Generates the Key used for decryption and encryption
   *
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  private void generateKeys() throws EncryptionException {

    try {
      String saltStr = "salty";// rbConfig.getString("salt");
      String passPhraseStr = "passy";// rbConfig.getString("passphrase");
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(saltStr) || StringUtils.isEmpty(passPhraseStr)) {
        throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL);
      }

      KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
      keyGen.initialize(512); // key size specified here.
      KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
      privateKeyParam = pair.getPrivate();
      publicKeyParam = pair.getPublic();

      /*-byte[] salt = saltStr.getBytes();
      int iterations = 10000;
      int keyLength = 128;

      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(passPhraseStr.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, keyLength));
      secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM_SHORT);*/
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } /*-catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
      }*/

  }

  /**
   * Test method
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] message = { "mktest", "9248547896548752345", "okok234234234okok467467",
        "12" };
    String result = null;
    try {
      SecurityTools secTool = new SecurityTools();
      PrivateKey priv = secTool.getPrivateKeyParam();
      PublicKey publ = secTool.getPublicKeyParam();
      String temp = "N5B1zgbvts3Vwrt6qyL/TBzt62HTFz0ISySx5HFu02oVq1YEhFLbrgdCndROX4/5hMpxCHGM8UJBSyZUfjD/DA==";
      // System.out.println("ASYMMETRIC TEST" + secTool.decrypt(temp, priv));

      for (String mess : message) {
        result = secTool.encrypt(mess, publ);
        System.out.println(result);
        result = secTool.decrypt(result, priv);
        System.out.println(result);
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }

  /**
   * @return the privateKeyParam
   */
  public PrivateKey getPrivateKeyParam() {
    return privateKeyParam;
  }

  /**
   * @return the publicKeyParam
   */
  public PublicKey getPublicKeyParam() {
    return publicKeyParam;
  }

  class EncryptionException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public EncryptionException() {}

    public EncryptionException(String message, Throwable cause) {
      super(message, cause);
    }

    public EncryptionException(String message) {
      super(message);
    }

    public EncryptionException(Throwable cause) {
      super(cause);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run that as-is it works because the main is doing the encryption and decryption all in one go.  However, when I take the output from a run, and store it in the temp String in main(), and then uncomment the line System.out.println("ASYMMETRIC TEST" +  is when it fails with

```
com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil.SecurityTools$EncryptionException: bad padding exception.
    at com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil.SecurityTools.decrypt(SecurityTools.java:154)
    at com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil.SecurityTools.main(SecurityTools.java:239)
Caused by: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:380)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:291)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:363)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:389)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2165)
    at com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil.SecurityTools.decrypt(SecurityTools.java:141)
    ... 1 more
```

I assume my issue is that I am re-generating a new KeyPair each time, which will only work the one time as a pair. So once I try to match a PrivateKey that came from one KeyPair to the text that was encrypted with an entirely different KeyPair, it fails.  But I have yet to find how you are supposed to otherwise achieve this in that case.

Comment: This is the closest I have found to an answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23086424/rsa-keys-keys-static-generation - Do I really have to find some way to store the private key in a shared space between the two applications?  AT that point, why don't I just forego encryption altogether, and have application 1 store its unencrypted value in a database that application 2 then retrieves to ensure it has not been tampered with??  Surely there is a better, correct way to do this!

Comment: Why not just use SSL/TLS?

Comment: @JamesKPolk The fact is I am not aware of this being an option. That is why I posted this, trying to find what I can try. In my full day of searching about encryption, this did not come up, so thanks.  Funnily enough it is slightly similar to the option I came up with on my drive home. I would have client A call client B, which would generate an ID and a salt and store it. Client A would use that salt to encrypt the ID I gave it, plus the other data it needs to encrypt. Then send that all back to client B to use for validation. Creating that initial contract sounds similar to SSL/TLS methods

Comment: I also realized that my initial approach is flawed no matter what. As long as an encrypted value can get decrypted in the destination system at any time, it does not matter if that encrypted value changes each session. Once a hacker has a working encrypted value for any given String which I expect my source system to decrypt, he can send whatever data he wants, if he has seen the desired value encrypted in a previous session. Since I am sending prices in these requests, it would not be hard to obtain a previous valid representation of any amount desired and use that for other calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
package com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.MissingResourceException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.ni.apps.cartencryptutil.exceptions.EncryptionException;

/**
 * Security class for encrypting and decrypting Strings (that also works in WC ver 7 and above).
 *
 * @author mkohanek
 *
 */
public class SecurityTools {
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SecurityTools.class);

  private Cipher cipher;
  private IvParameterSpec initVector;
  private SecretKey secretKey;
  private transient ResourceBundle rbConfig;

  private static SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
  private static final String AES_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
  private static final String ALGORITHM_SHORT = "AES";
  private static final String PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithMD5AndDES";
  private static final String UTF8 = "UTF-8";
  private static final int ITERATIONS = 10000;
  private static final int KEY_LENGTH = 128;

  // exceptions
  private static final String _ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE = "illegal block size exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_BAD_PADDING = "bad padding exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALIDKEY = "invalidkey exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_PADDING = "padding exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM = "no such algorithm exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL = "passphrase is null.";
  private static final String _ERR_SALT_IS_NULL = "salt is null.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM = "invalid algorithm exception.";
  private static final String _ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING = "encoding not supported.";
  private static final String _ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC = "invalid key spec exception.";

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param salt
   *          - for encryption, obtain salt from generateSalt(). for decryption, you should use the same salt used during encryption
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public SecurityTools(String salt) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering Constructor");
    }
    try {
      loadProperties();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);
      generateIV(salt);
      generateKey(salt);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting Constructor");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Constructor
   *
   * @param salt
   *          - for encryption, obtain salt from generateSalt(). for decryption, you should use the same salt used during encryption
   * @param passPhrase
   *          - Allows client to pass in a passphrase it wants to use rather than use the one this library defines. This must also be used when decrypting. The length limit for this key is 16
   *          characters
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public SecurityTools(String salt, String passPhrase) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering Constructor");
    }
    try {
      loadProperties();
      cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_ALGORITHM);
      generateIV(salt);
      generateKey(salt, passPhrase);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException nspe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PADDING, nspe);
    }
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting Constructor");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Encrypts a given plain text String, and returns the encrypted String
   *
   * @param plainText
   * @return
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public String encrypt(String plainText) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering encrypt");
    }

    String encryptedKey = null;
    try {
      byte[] byteToEncrypt = plainText.getBytes(UTF8);
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, initVector, new SecureRandom());
      byte[] encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(byteToEncrypt);
      encryptedKey = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(encryptedBytes);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
    } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException uee) {
      logger.error(_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING, uee);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_UNSUPPORTED_ENCODING, uee);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting encrypt");
    }

    return encryptedKey;
  }

  /**
   * Decrypts a given encrypted String, and returns the plain text String
   *
   * @param cipherTextStr
   * @return
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  public String decrypt(String cipherTextStr) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering decrypt");
    }

    String cleartext = null;
    try {
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, initVector);
      byte[] plainByte = cipher.doFinal(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(cipherTextStr));
      cleartext = new String(plainByte);
    } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException iape) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_ALGORITHM, iape);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException ike) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALIDKEY, ike);
    } catch (BadPaddingException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_BAD_PADDING, bpe);
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException bpe) {
      logger.error(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_ILLEGAL_BLOCK_SIZE, bpe);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting decrypt");
    }

    return cleartext;
  }

  /**
   * Creates the IV using Secure Random Number Generator and an empty 16byte array
   *
   * @return
   */
  private void generateIV(String salt) {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering generateIV");
    }

    byte[] newSeed = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(salt);
    initVector = new IvParameterSpec(newSeed);

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting generateIV");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Generates the Key used for decryption and encryption using passphrase from properties file on library
   *
   ** @param saltStr
   * @return
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  private void generateKey(String saltStr) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering generateKey");
    }

    try {
      String passPhraseStr = rbConfig.getString("passphrase");
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(passPhraseStr)) {
        throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL);
      }
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(saltStr)) {
        throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_SALT_IS_NULL);
      }

      byte[] salt = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(saltStr);

      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(passPhraseStr.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH));
      secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM_SHORT);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting generateKey");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Generates the Key used for decryption and encryption using passphrase passed in
   *
   * @param saltStr
   * @param passPhrase
   * @throws EncryptionException
   */
  private void generateKey(String saltStr, String passPhrase) throws EncryptionException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("entering generateKey");
    }

    try {
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(passPhrase)) {
        throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_PASSPHRASE_IS_NULL);
      }
      if (StringUtils.isEmpty(saltStr)) {
        throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_SALT_IS_NULL);
      }

      byte[] salt = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(saltStr);

      SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM);
      SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, ITERATIONS, KEY_LENGTH));
      secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), ALGORITHM_SHORT);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException iae) {
      logger.error(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_NO_SUCH_ALGORITHM, iae);
    } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
      logger.error(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
      throw new EncryptionException(_ERR_INVALID_KEY_SPEC, e);
    }

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
      logger.debug("exiting generateKey");
    }
  }

  /**
   * This generates a random value of user defined size that can be used to encrypt data. The decrypting client will then need to access this value to be able to decrypt
   *
   * @return
   */
  public static String generateSaltStr(int size) {
    String salt = null;
    byte[] newSeed = secureRandom.generateSeed(size);
    salt = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(newSeed);

    return salt;
  }

  /**
   * This generates a random 16 bit value that can be used to encrypt data. The decrypting client will then need to access this value to be able to decrypt
   *
   * @return
   */
  public static String generateSaltStr() {
    String salt = null;
    byte[] newSeed = secureRandom.generateSeed(16);
    salt = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(newSeed);

    return salt;
  }

  /**
   * Loads properties files (call before attempting to read any properties files)
   */
  private void loadProperties() {
    try {
      rbConfig = ResourceBundle.getBundle("application", Locale.US);
    } catch (MissingResourceException ie) {
      logger.fatal(
          "FATAL: SecurityTools.loadProperties Cannot read the properties file.  Please ensure the file is on the classpath.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.fatal(
          "FATAL: SecurityTools.loadProperties Cannot read the properties file.  Please ensure the file is on the classpath.");
    }
  }

  /**
   * Test method
   *
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] message = { "mkohanek", "9248547896548752345", "okok234234234okok467467",
        "12" };
    String result = null;
    try {
      // ASYMMETRIC TEST - use this block to test values are usable over separate sessions by taking output from loop below and using it here for subsequent calls
      // String previousSalt = "jriUh+01HlHw4g3mO9PLcw==";
      // SecurityTools asSecTool = new SecurityTools(previousSalt);
      // String previousEncryptedValue = "nFVxkzdx+psiUVkCW5NztQ==";
      // System.out.println("should decrypt to an expected value - " + asSecTool.decrypt(previousEncryptedValue));
      // END ASYMMETRIC TEST

      // SYMMETRIC TEST - tests that single requests will encrypt and decrypt successfully
      String salt = generateSaltStr(16);
      System.out.println("salt - " + salt);
      SecurityTools secTool = new SecurityTools(salt);
      for (String mess : message) {
        result = secTool.encrypt(mess);
        System.out.println(result);
        result = secTool.decrypt(result);
        System.out.println(result);
      }
      // END SYMMETRIC TEST
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();

    }
  }

}
```